# Which adjective is the most suitable to express "rich" for a person?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

In Mandarin there are a variety of adjectives that express "rich" - 富，丰富，肥，充实，阔，丰盛，浓郁，富足，etc...

Some of them I believe don't fit in a person; 肥 is an equivalent to "fertile" in English, 浓郁 is "dense", etc...

But I can't decide which is the correct adjective among 富，丰富，富足，丰盛, etc...

The example:

> 年轻中国女人很___。
>
> 为什么华人那么___?

In these cases, which adjective is the most suitable to express "rich"?

Also, in these cases (irrespective of the term "rich"), how can I know which adjective is the most suitable in a context?

Comment: 富，丰富，富足，丰盛，see dictionaries supplied examples showing collocation:(only the 1st can apply to person, in fixed expressions, **bound morpheme** ) 
**富**  1) s.v. wealthy; abundant（财产多） wealthy; rich:
富商 wealthy merchant
富人 rich man
（丰富; 多） rich; abundant:
年富力强 in one's prime
富于养分 be rich in nutrition
富于自我批评精神 be imbued with the spirit of self-criticism
富于创造性 be highly creative
他们把富日子当穷日子过。 They are thrifty even in days of affluence.
**丰富** （种类多; 数量大） abundant; ample; aplenty; rich; plentiful:
丰富的经验 rich experience
资源丰富 rich in natural resources
她的想象力非常丰富。

Comment: She has plenty of imagination.
**富足**   丰富充足：过着富足的日子。[plentiful; abundant] 丰富而充足的
富足的国家
财物丰足。
 **丰盛**   丰富<指物质方面>：丰盛的酒席。
 
[sumptuous; rich] 食物丰富; 充足
丰盛的一餐
 
丰富而繁盛。rich; sumptuous; bumper:
1) 犹盛多。
2) 犹丰熟。
3) 犹兴盛。
II
指丰满的祭器，内装黍稷一类祭品。丰盛的酒席 a sumptuous feast
丰盛的筵席 a feast of fat things,

Comment: 土豪 - probably the best

Comment: rich person (see dictionaries) 有钱,有财的人，ichacha：wealthy  财产多的，富有的；丰富的，充分的；大量的  a wealthy family 豪门春色 very wealthy 极有钱 wealthy family 富裕家庭 used  **predicatively**  ：as rich as croesus ie very rich 像克罗伊斯那样  **富有**  be very rich and generous  **富有**  又出手大方  **土豪**  bkrs：local tyrant
local strong man
(slang) nouveau riche
local despot
local tyrant
1) 地方上有钱 **有势**  的家族或个人。
2) 特指乡村中有钱 **有势的恶霸** 。
3) 一方的 **首领** 。

Comment: 丰富 is rich in resources, but usually not for money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 年轻中国女人很___。
>
> 为什么华人那么___?

In your context, among those words you listed,  only 富 is appropriate. 富 means 富有；有钱；having lots of money.

肥 can also fit, but it will mean fat, which would be an insult.

阔 might be also ok, meaning "having lots of money or able to spend lots of money". But it's not that common as 富 or 有钱.

The rest 丰盛，浓郁，富足 are usually used to describe things, conditions and etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of comments

Comment: @user6065 Why do you usually leave a comment but never write an answer?

Comment: 富 is one-syllable word, so if there is a case that a two-syllables word fits better, which word should I use?

Comment: duck test 鸭子测试: 如果它看起来像鸭子，游泳像鸭子，叫声像鸭子，那么它可能就是只鸭子。

Comment: @Blaszard,富有 can be used in this context.